# LEFT Join does not pull record from main table if the JOINED value is null

Tags: sql, ssms

Say I have a tableA that looks like this:

```
 ID         Name         IssueID
 1          Bob          2
 2          John         Null
```

I have my Reference table called tblRef that includes these columns:

```
 IssueID       IssueDesc
 2             Not Completed
 3             Completed
```

My query looks something like this,

```
Select a.Id,a.Name, I.IssueDesc from tableA a Left Join tblRef I on a.issueId = 
I.IssueDesc where IssueID not in (2)
```

If I do this, I do not see the record from tableA where the IssueID is NULL, is there any way to pull it up? Or rather why isn't it pulling up the record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NULL` "fails" almost all comparisons.  What actually happens is that the result is `NULL`, and the rows get filtered out.

In SQL Server, you need to test for this explicitly:

```
where IssueID not in (2) OR IssueID is null
```

Remember that the semantics of `NULL` generally have it meaning "unknown" value rather than "missing" value.  When you have `NULL not in (2)`, the semantics are " not in (2)".  The result is "unknown", because the value *could* be 2.

Comment: +1 When you're trying to compare an unknown value to any other value, the result is always unknown and not included in the results.